# For every $P$ in an irreducible smooth projective curve exists a differential 1-form $\omega$ such that $\omega(P)\neq 0$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth irreducible projective curve and $P\in X$. Suppose that the genus $g>0$. Knowing that $1 = \dim H^{0}(X,\mathcal{O}_{X}(P)) = \dim H^{1}(X,\mathcal{O}_{X}(K_{X}-P))$. I want to show that there exists a $\omega\in \Omega_{X}^{1}(X)$ such that $\omega(P)\neq 0$.

Let $K_{X}$ be a canonical divisor, then by Riemann-Roch we find that 
$\dim H^{0}(X,\mathcal{O}_{X}(K_{X}-P)) - \dim H^{1}(X,\mathcal{O}_{X}(K_{X}-P))
= \deg(K_{X}) - g = g-2$. Consequently we see that $\dim H^{0}(X,\mathcal{O}_{X}(K_{X}-P)) = g-1$. And notice that we thus find

$\dim H^{0}(X,\mathcal{O}_{X}(K_{X}-P)) = \dim H^{0}(X,\Omega_{X}^{1}(-P))\geqslant 0$.

From here I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you had it just fine. So $\dim H^0(X,\Omega^1_X(-P)) = g-1$. Since $\dim H^0(X,\Omega^1_X) = g > g-1$, it follows that the subspace of $1$-forms vanishing at $P$ is a hyperplane, and that leaves us plenty of $1$-forms that do not vanish at $P$ — namely, the complement of this hyperplane.

**COMMENT**: Just to check intuition. When $g=1$, the only $1$-form vanishing at $P$ is the identically $0$ form. If we think of $X$ as $\Bbb C/\Lambda$, all the $1$-forms are constant multiples of $dz$.

Comment: To be sure, $H^{0}(X,\Omega_{X}^{1}(-P))$ I can see as the differential one forms with at least a zero in $P$ and no poles and $H^{0}(X,\Omega_{X}^{1})$ as the set of differential one forms with no poles?

Comment: Right, those are holomorphic sections of the sheaf of (germs of) holomorphic $1$-forms.